# Enable MySQL to use more than 1 core (multicore)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, sql

I am running a very intensive MySQL query and noticed that only 1 core is being used to 100% while the other cores are idle. The system is running Ubuntu 12.04 and MySQL 5.5.28

Is there a way to force MySQL to use all cores?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nope. MySQL query planner doesn't support multi-CPUs.

See also:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15146/using-multiple-cores-for-single-mysql-queries-on-debian
- http://searchsystemschannel.techtarget.com/feature/Using-Parallel-SQL-to-improve-Oracle-database-performance